# Bytes reserved in memory for new object

Tags: c#, memory-management, new-operator

AFAIK, all types are derived from

```
 System.Object class.
```

Considering this, how can I calculate how many bytes the following code is taking:

```
Employee emp = new Employee("emp_name");
```

and

```
 List<string> empList = new List<string>();
```

What is the best and appropriate method to calculate the bytes they are taking?

Comment: What's motivating the question? What are you planning to do with the information?

Comment: The question you ask in the title is not the same as the question you ask in the body. The title asks about the bytes in memory for an object, whereas the body asks about the bytes in memory for an object hierarchy. (Note that objects in a hierarchy can be shared, so that complicates the calculations.) And of course there's the question of what you intend to do with this information.

Comment: @Raymond I am reading book, CLR via C#, there I got a sentence which encouraged me to ask this question. I have no such intention to bump this code byte into Microsoft toolkit to improve it's performance. SO is for sharing knowledge, may be I missed the title with the subject and I regret for that... may be because I'm from non-native English speaker country. I have started learning English just 5 years back, so I beg your pardon for that genuine mistake. Perhaps, I would be thankful if you could share your knowledge on this topic :-)

Comment: Are you interested in the size of a single object (e.g., `Employee`, `List<string>`), or interested in the size of an object hierarchy (e.g. `Employee` + the string `"emp_name"` + any other things the `Employee` has a reference to; `List<string>` + the sizes of all the strings inside the list)?

Comment: @RaymondChen I am interested in all things which are a part of object like you have mentioned (**e.g. Employee + the string "emp_name" + any other things the Employee has a reference to**)

Comment: Note that if you go that route, you may end up double-counting. For example, `Employee emp1 = new Employee("emp_name"); Employee emp2 = new Employee("emp_name");` You will count the string `"emp_name"` twice, even though there is only one copy in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the C# `sizeof` operator but it is quite limited because you have to specify the type at compile time and it can only be used on built-in types. For you `Employee` class you can add these together to determine the size of class. However, all reference types in the `Employee` class (like `String`) are separately allocated on the heap and you will have to add the size of these objects to get the total size.

With some IL trickery you can use the following method to compute how many bytes a value type (`struct`) requires. For reference types it will always return the size of a reference (4 bytes on 32 bit):

```
public int GetSizeOf(Type type) {
  // Create a new method.
  var method = new DynamicMethod(
    "GetSizeOf",
    typeof(UInt32),
    new Type[0],
    GetType(),
    false
  );

  // Call sizeof(type) and return the result.
  ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();
  generator.Emit(OpCodes.Sizeof, type);
  generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

  // Invoke the method.
  var func = (Func<UInt32>) method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<UInt32>));
  return checked((Int32) func());
}
```

However, even using `sizeof` to compute bytes isn't entirely accurate. Objects on the heap will have an additional type handle which is like a vtable pointer in C++. Exactly how this is done is an implementation detail of the .NET runtime.

Comment: I find it very hard to calculate a real world class (e.g.  with reference and generic lists ...). right now, this just tells you the structure size. nothing more. and this function ( like you said ) doesnt calculate all descendant and reference objects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to none other than [Vance Morrison](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/96747ab7-7d89-4846-9e83-46f71b8ccc66), there is no official way to determine this. All hope is not lost though, and you do have a few options (off the top of my head):

- binary serialization/deserialization (as described by Royi Namir)
- reflection (recursively add up all field sizes until the object graph is fully discovered); or
- brute force (create a large array of your objects, measure allocated memory before/after your allocation using the GC.GetTotalMemory() static method, and divide by the array size)

All of these solutions can only approximate the allocation size, unfortunately, until (if at all) Microsoft officially adds such a feature.